# Оптимизация. Ускорение сайта

Tags: css, оптимизация

Когда воспользовалась сервисом PageSpeed Insights, обнаружила, что требуется:

> Исправьте обязательно: Удалите из верхней части страницы код JavaScript и CSS, блокирующий отображение
>
> Количество блокирующих скриптов на странице: 3.
>   Количество блокирующих ресурсов CSS на странице: 5.
>   Удалите код JavaScript, препятствующий отображению:
>
> ```
> http://eco-turizm.net/…ntent/themes/turisme/jquery.js?ver=3.9.5
> http://eco-turizm.net/…ntent/themes/turisme/script.js?ver=3.9.5
> http://eco-turizm.net/…s/turisme/script.responsive.js?ver=3.9.5
> ```
>
> Оптимизируйте работу CSS на следующих ресурсах:
>
> ```
> http://eco-turizm.net/…/A.style.css.pagespeed.cf.IOwq-urdC1.css
> http://eco-turizm.net/…ss,qver=2.69.pagespeed.cf.uGPlOiFioZ.css
> http://eco-turizm.net/…s,qver=2.3.1.pagespeed.cf.3zvcGKDV_-.css
> http://eco-turizm.net/…s,qver=3.9.5.pagespeed.cf.TvzLgYPSmo.css
> http://fonts.googleapis.com/…s?family=Artifika&subset=latin&ver=3.9.5
> ```

Вот это "Удалите код..." не очень понятно. Я удалила эти три файла, но пришлось вернуть обратно, т.к. шапка сайта не загружалась.

Объясните *чайнику*, как склеить css в один файл и минизировать (сжать, как я понимаю).

На хостинге, в разделе "Настройки оптимизации сайта" есть опции "Объединить файлы style.css в один файл". Это то, что нужно сделать? А каким образом его сжать?

Ещё я не знаю, как выполнить пункт "Оптимизируйте работу CSS".

Прошу объясните или дайте ссылку на вменяемую статью для начинающих.

Answer (score 2):

В самом `PageSpeed Insights`, во вкладке "Для компьютеров" в самом низу страницы есть ссылка "Скачать оптимизированные изображения, ресурсы JavaScript и CSS для этой страницы". Отсюда можно взять CSS и JavaScript.

Кроме того, сам Гугл Предлагает подключать CSS после закрывающего тэга `</html>`, это не совсем валидно, но действительно ускоряет загрузку страницы. Чтоб страница первые секунды не отображалась без стилей, я в секции `<head>` документа прописываю

```
<style>
    body{visibility: hidden;}
</style>
```

А в конец CSS добавляю `body {visibility: visible;}`

И еще, скрипты по возможности подключать в конце документа, перед `</body>` со свойством `defer`.

Answer (score 0):

Под "Удалите из верхней части страницы код JavaScript" скорее всего имелось введу что лучше перенести его вниз страницы, а не удалять совсем. Попробуйте перенести подключение скриптов ближе к футеру. 
Подключение CSS лучше перенести наоборот вверх страницы.
[Статья про оптимизацию](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137239/)
 
[Cервисы для сжатия CSS](http://nicothin.ru/page/4-servisa-dlya-szhatiya-css.html) - насколько я понимаю(сама к сожалению не пользовалась), нужно скопировать код CSS-файла в форму, сделать сжатие и сжатый код скопировать обратно в файл. Можно приписать к расширению `min.css` .

Comment: Как выглядит код JavaScript и в каком файле он сидит? В файле Заголовка? Я где-то читала, что перенос с верхней части в нижнюю вызывает у посетителей сайта "прыгающую" страницу во время ее загрузки. Так ли это?

Comment: @Татьяна, перед оптимизацией было бы очень не плохо разобраться сначала в теме, хотя бы немного. Ознакомиться с js можно [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/tutorial)

Comment: подключение выглядит вот так `<script src="/js/script1.js"></script>`, находится скорее всего в файле header.php, если такой есть. "Прыгающая" страница действительно может быть если скрипты влияют на отображение, попробуйте перенести и если будут проблемы - верните обратно. Если не знаете какие скрипты могут влиять на отображение страницы можете по-экспериментировать, по одному переносить подключение скриптов.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Для склеивания - перенесите все css стили в один основной

***Важно! Будьте аккуратны при объединении файлов стилей! Всегда оставляйте возможность вернуть все на свои места, если что-то пойдет не так.***

**2.** Подключение для гугл шрифта

```
$("head").append("<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/…s?family=Artifika&subset=latin&ver=3.9.5' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");
```

**3.** Скрипты для ускорения загрузки лучше перенести вниз

**4.** По поводу сжатия CSS и JS файлов (минимизация) – на некоторых хостингах присутствует возможность включения функции предварительной минимизации этих файлов. Сервер берет ваш файл, и минимизирует его, удаляя все пробелы, разрывы строк и из красивого и форматированного файла вы получаете одну строку, уменьшая таким образом меньший размер файла и соответственно уменьшая скорость его загрузки.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно получить хорошие цифры — выносим стили, которые относятся к шапке, меню и первому экрану в head, просто инлайново.

Все остальные стили и скрипты подключаем либо динамически (с помощью js), либо просто пихаем в конец html документа, перед закрывающим

Картинки можно сжать через tinyPNG, также желательно нарезать под разные разрешения.

Но, в целом, скорость современного интернета позволяет сильно не париться об этом