# Как удалить из верхней части страницы код JavaScript и CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, joomla, оптимизация

Занялась оптимизацией сайта, сервис https://developers.google.com выдал рекомендацию: "Удалите из верхней части страницы код JavaScript и CSS, блокирующий отображение". Не знаю, как это сделать, сайт на джумле. Смотрела шаблон - там нет подключений скриптов, видимо, в каком-то другом файле. 
Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему? Читала на форумах, что можно не удалять (если без этих скриптов не возможна работа сайта), а просто переместить или сделать так, чтобы скрипты подгружались после загрузки основного контента. Вот эти скрипты гугл советует удалить:

```
http://nastroike.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js
http://nastroike.com/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js
http://nastroike.com/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js
http://nastroike.com/media/system/js/caption.js
http://nastroike.com/media/system/js/mootools-core.js
http://nastroike.com/media/system/js/core.js
http://nastroike.com/media/system/js/mootools-more.js
http://nastroike.com/media/system/js/html5fallback.js
```

Comment: FAQ Ускоряем загрузку сайта (руководства и инструменты) http://joomlaforum.ru/index.php/topic,213307.msg1198234.html#msg1198234

Comment: Вопрос уже задавался [недавно](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419920/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0/419933)

Comment: Это мне не подходит, т.к. там сайт не на джумле, и код можно свободно убрать, у меня же проблема в том, что я не знаю, где подключаются скрипты, в шаблоне этого нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все это можно найти в /libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php

Answer (score -1):

Или есть способ прописать всем скриптам joomla загрузку `async="async"`
В файле :

> libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php

дописать в строчку

```
$buffer .= $tab . '<script src="' . $strSrc . '" async="async"';
```